# pandas interrows too slow. what is a faster alternative for following code?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance

I have a dataset of about 600,000 rows. The following code takes a long time to run due to the use of pandas iterrows(). Are there any alternatives which are suitable for the specific code shown below

```
%%time
import numpy as np
df_inputed = df # dataframe with many missing values
for index, row in df_to_inpute.iterrows(): 
    sic = row['sic']
    year = row['year']
    quarter = row['quarter']
    for col in cols_to_check: #columns except for date and pk columns
        value = row[col]
        if np.isnan(value): 
            median = get_median(sic, year, quarter) #assume operation is O(1) time
            if not np.isnan(median): 
                df_inputed.at[index, col] = median
```

Comment: what's `get_median` in your case?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Hi thanks for the reply, for getMedian(), i have a dataframe which is grouped by sic, year and quarter. The function then identifies the row for the given sic, year and quarter, and returns the value for the column in the loop. Using df.apply() takes about 2 hours to run, much better than iterrows. not sure if there is better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With combination of `df.apply` + [`pd.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) methods:

```
def fill_with_median(x):
    if x[cols_to_check].isna().any():  # if filling is needed
        med = x[cols_median].median()
        if not np.isnan(med):
            x[cols_to_check] = x[cols_to_check].fillna(med)
    return x

cols_median = ['sic', 'year', 'quarter']

df = df.apply(fill_with_median, axis=1)
```

---

Another way is using *boolean masks* to filter the needed slices for filling:

```
m = df[cols_to_check].isna().any(axis=1)
med_vals = df[cols_median][m].median(1)
df.loc[m & med_vals.notna(), cols_to_check] = med_vals
```